# How to switch from Linux Ubuntu to windows 8.1

Tags: windows

I have no knowledge of Ubuntu at all. I don't know how to preform a system wipe nor preform a BIOS boot; all my knowledge on these are in windows OS's. I literally just built my first PC and just wanted a free OS, that is why I downloaded it in the first place. I just want to switch back for compatibility reasons. Also i don't particularly know much about computers either, for instance I was looking around and i found out about partition drives and gParting, I didn't know about these prior to looking.

Comment: @Pilot6 - While it is a dupe, I feel my answer here is much faster and more straight forward.

Comment: We do not need many answers of this kind.

Answer (score -1):

It's very easy!

1) Boot your Windows install DVD

2) Progress though the screens until you see "Setup is starting". Wait till you land on the next screen.

3) At that point do not continue further in the installation screens until doing steps 4-6

4) Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

5) In the CMD Window, type the following:

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk 0 #Replace the "0" accordingly
clean
exit
exit
```

6) Continue on with the install. You disk has been wiped!